# Change Site "Web Hosting Plane" on Azure

Tags: azure

in Tab "Scale" on a Azure web site i've the list of sites of the "Web Hosting Plane" linked to this web site.
How can I split this plane in two planes? 
I've to scale only one site end not all the sites of the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to migrate your specific site to a new hosting plan, which you should also create. It can only be done via command shell at the moment.

[This article should give you a good direction](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/)